# Timestamp multiple cells in one sheet upon update of adjacent cell - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which needs sign off by multiple managers.

The format of the sheet (Payroll) is simply

Name of Manager (column D) Timestamp (column E)

They are protected cells locked down to the user signing off.

So when they enter their name in the manager column the timestamp is added automatically.

I was using the NOW() function but that obviously isn't a timestamp and I've tried adapting versions I've found on here but I'm struggling to get it to work as they're all very specific to the usecase of the question.

I have tried this which was supplied by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper in another thread but I think...and stress the word think...that that will work on any column 1-6?

So in my example would I just change the e.range.columnStart=4 and the rowStart>189 (row 189 is where the signoff block is) - I've tried this but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong as nothing happens!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart < 7 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    sh.getRange(1, 2).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (sh.getName() == "Payroll" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Edit column D with row > 1 and receive time stamp in e.range.rowStart and column 5

Comment: Thanks again, much appreciated I shall give this a try.